# What does the term "method" apply to in Python?

Tags: python

From The Python Tutorial:

> (In Python, the term method is not unique to class instances: other object types can have methods as well. For example, list objects have methods called append, insert, remove, sort, and so on.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects, 25.04.2020.

Surely list objects are class instances as well? So the quote doesn't really provide any examples of other object types that have methods?

So: can the term "method" refer to, in Python, other things than functions associated with instances of classes?

Comment: "For example, list objects have methods called append, insert, remove, sort, and so on. However, in the following discussion, we’ll use the term method exclusively to mean methods of class instance objects, unless explicitly stated otherwise.)" You seem to have skipped the totally relevant second sentence from your quote

Comment: Actually, now I've got myself a bit confused about your second quote having read through it

Comment: "By definition, all attributes of a class that are function objects define corresponding methods of its instances. So in our example, x.f is a valid method reference, since MyClass.f is a function, but x.i is not, since MyClass.i is not. But x.f is not the same thing as MyClass.f — it is a method object, not a function object." - I think some more context might help

Comment: That comment could be clearer. It's referring to *user-defined* classes, which is probably what a newcomer to the language would think is synonymous with "class". However, Python no longer makes a distinction between class and type; `list` is a class/type, and `append` et al. are methods of that class/type.

Comment: The second comment alludes to the descriptor protocol. Because `f` is a `function` object (and `function` implements the descriptor protocol), `MyClass.f` triggers a method call `MyClass.__dict__['f'].__get__(None, MyClass)`, which returns the function itself. `x.f` triggers the call `type(x).__dict__['f'].__get__(x, type(x))`, which returns an instance of `method` that wraps both the original function and `x`.

Comment: @roganjosh 
The following might be wrong in my original comment:
" But x.f is not the same thing as MyClass.f — it is a method object, not a function object. "
I took that to mean that MyClass.f is not a method / method object, and further that classes can't have methods / method objects. But maybe I should have interpreted it as "classes can't have methods / methods objects *as defined in this document*". But even then, can we say that classes CAN have methods in general python jargon, and that the the original quote meant the list class when talking about list objects?

Comment: People loosely refer to `function`-valued class attributes as methods, but a `method` is what gets *created* when you access such an attribute from an instance of the class.

Comment: You might want to read the [descriptor how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). (Actually, you may want to read it several times; it took me a long time to really understand it.) The short version is, `MyClass.f` gives you the actual `function` object defined in the `class` statement; `x.f` gives you a callable object that calls `MyClass.f` with `x` and whatever other arguments are given. (That's why `x.f(a, b, c)` is roughly equivalent to `MyClass.f(x, a, b, c)`.)

Comment: @chepner "x.f gives you a callable object that calls MyClass.f ..." Except when x.f is explicitly redefined to be another function? That might just be nitpicking.

Comment: It is :) The key is that once the attribute lookup determines what exactly the `f` attribute refers to, it checks if that value implements `__get__`; if it does, you get back the return value of a call to `__get__`, rather than the attribute value itself. See this [blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/) (ignore the title; you're looking for the fantastic flow charts that describe how attribute lookup proceeds and evaluates).

Comment: I think the second quote is confusing and was stupid to include, as I want to talk about the term "method" in general python terms, wheras that quote might use the document-specific meaning of the word. I'll edit it out, but will store it (not that any of you would be likely to want to review it.)

Comment: @chepner I'll read through your comments later and try to figure things out. Thanks.

Comment: @Skeptic I've added my first comment as an answer to address your edited question.

Answer (score 2):

That sentence refers to a distinction between types and (user-defined) classes that once existed in Python 2, but no longer exists in Python 3. A type is a class, a class is a type, and `list` has methods just the same as a user-defined class.

It could be considered an inaccuracy in the tutorial that should be corrected, but at the same time you can consider it as intentional "white lie" for people accustomed to other languages in which there is a clear distinction between primitive types and class types. (E.g., `int` vs `Integer` in Java.)